# How to dismiss a popup bubble with one click over ono-popup region

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am using the following code to create a popup bubble when a user double-clicks on the webpage:

```
function displaySomething(x, y) {
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.id = "displaySomething_div";
    ....
}

var listener = function (event) {
    if (event.button == 0 ) {
        var div = document.getElementById("displaySomething_div");
    if (div) {
        document.body.removeChild(div);
    }
        displaySomething(event.pageX, event.pageY);
    } 
};

document.addEventListener("dblclick", listener, false);
```

Currently, the popup bubble will only be dismissed when I double-click on the page or on the bubble.

Is it possible to dismiss the popup bubble only when a single-click over non-bubble area of the page is made? That is, if I click or select over the bubble, the bubble will stay there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a click handler to the popup div which stops propagation of the click event, and then you can safely attach a click handler to the document parent.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/M6asx/

```
function displaySomething(x, y) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.id = "displaySomething_div";
    ...
    div.addEventListener('click', function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); }, false);
}

var listener = function (event) {
    if (event.button == 0) {
        var div = document.getElementById("displaySomething_div");
        if (div) {
            document.body.removeChild(div);
        } else {
            displaySomething(event.pageX, event.pageY);
        }
    }
};

document.addEventListener('click', listener, false);
```

Comment: `stopPropagation()` works perfectly in my scenario. Thank you very much!